# <select> inside a modal form

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

i'm trying to create a select through jquery i can create inputs , but for some reason i it gives me error on a `<select>`. Here is the code

```
 var form1 = bootbox.confirm("<form id='infos' action=''>\
    <label>Titulo:</label><input autocomplete=off type=text name='title' /><br/>\
    <label>Turno</label><select name='select'>
  <option value='value1'>Value 1</option> 
  <option value='value2'>Value 2</option>
  <option value='value3'>Value 3</option>
</select><br/>\
    <label></label><br/>\
      <label></label><br/>\
       <label></label><br/>\
    </form>", function(result) {
        if(result)
                var nomestaff = document.getElementById("inputString").value;
                var idstaff = document.getElementById("inputString2").value;
                 var title = form1.find("input[name=title]").val();
                  var turno = form1.find("input[name=turno]").val();
                   var start2 = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   var end2 = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                  alert(start2);
                  $.ajax({
   url: 'add_eventshorario.php',
   data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start2 +'&end='+ end2 +'&url='+  utente +'&local='+ local +'&meiotransporte='+  meiotransporte  +'&acompanhante='+ acompanhante +'&tipoconsulta='+ tipo_consulta +'&nomeutente='+ nomeutente  ,
   type: "POST",
   success: function(json) {
   alert(nomeutente);
   location.reload();
```

Comment: Show us your `full code`, it is `partial`(Missing closing braces of `Ajax` and `Function`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to `escape` `select string` too like,

```
...
<label>Turno</label><select name='select'>\
  <option value='value1'>Value 1</option> \
  <option value='value2'>Value 2</option>\
  <option value='value3'>Value 3</option>\
</select><br/>\
....
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3JRA7/)